# OpenCV and iOS in an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

We have built a desktop application in java which uses OpenCV.
We would like to build a similar app for iPhone. Is OpenCV available by default in iOS?
If that is not the case, is the user required to download and install openCV separately for iPhone to use the app dependent on OpenCV?

Is there a way build the app in such a way that all of its dependencies are self-contained i.e. even if the app uses OpenCV, the user need not install OpenCV separately? If so how to do it? I can't find any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No open CV is not in objective-c by default so you have to download the library and install it first them develop the app and compile it with the library.
http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Yes, you can build it as self contained app if you add the framework to the dependencies section in Xcode. Apple will not allow the user to download and install stuff on the iphone each app is downloaded separately.